# Play multiple wav audio with C and libao at same time

Tags: c, gcc, audio, wav, alsa

I'm using libao (ao_play) to play some buffers. I listen the keyboard keys and for each key I have a wav sound to play. It's simple.

With ao_play I see that the application blocks while is playing the sound. Because I want to play multiple audios at same time, I needed to use threads (with pthread lib).

It works, but I fell like a workaround and if I play to much files (maybe 10 or something like this) so everything stuck for some seconds and so come back.

Well, my question is: how to play multiple sounds at same time non-blocking using libao (and not using threads)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This not a real design, more like a guess.

First of all, you'll need threads because it's a good old tradition to separate computations from visualisations, or audializations in this case. You'll need an audio thread that renders the stream and sends it to the output.

So, each time your main thread discovers a keypress, it sends a note to the audio thread. That latter captures an event and adds a wave to the currently played stream. The stream is rendered in frames (64, or 1024, or 10240 samples, or whatever you fancy your latency, if the wave itself is a simple mix of few possible samples, it can be notably realtime.) You should keep track of notes currently played, position per each sample. If latency is low, thus granularity high, you can even align sample edges by buffer edges, which would notably simplify rendering.

And after current buffer is rendered you simply send it to DAC and proceed with the next frame.

A quick glance at libao's help page does not reveal any mixing capabilities, so you'll need to create a simple mixer on your own, or you may actually need an existing solution, some simple opensource audio rendering library.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out that the thing is a mixer. SDL is a better option instead of libao